# In Fallout 3 (on the Xbox 360) is there any fix for the "moving PIP-Boy" bug?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-3

I love me some Fallout 3. In fact, it's paused as I write this.

That said, there's a fairly well-known bug (definitely in the Xbox version, I don't know about the others) where the PIP-Boy display shifts up occasionally, and eventually (if you access your PIP-Boy enough) the top portion is off the display, rendering the top line of information (say, your HP and weight carried) invisible.

Is there a fix for this aside from quitting and restarting the game?

Comment: Have an "I have this problem too" upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your PIP light on and off, if that doesnt work, wait for it to be patched.

Answer (score 1):

I have not experienced this bug, so I could not test. But I did find out that a proposed solution is to turn your PIP Boy light on and off.

Originally posted at [Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/rpg/fallout3/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-46516202&pid=939933)

Comment: Next time I get this glitch happening, I'll be sure to test it. (It just happened again the other day ... )

Answer (score 0):

I never experienced that problem, but Pip-Boy whiteouts were fairly common. Save and reload was the only consistent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a soulution, just save, exit the game, then once you are at the xbox home screen, return back to the game. If that dosen't work, try saving and then turning off the consul.

Comment: Thanks, but "aside from quitting and restarting the game." And that's what this solution is. :)